# SetImageDrawable in a list view

Tags: java, android, android-listview, imageview, drawable

In my list view, I want to make it so that it will change the drawable in the image view i made, but I get an error every time I run it.

```
ImageView Player;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Player = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.bob);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.pointguards, PointGuards));
    final ListView lv = getListView();
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    String item = (String) lv.getAdapter().getItem(position);
                    //decide how to launch `Intent` depending on `item`
                    if (item == "bob"){
                Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.nba.playerinfo");
                startActivity(intent);
                Player.setImageDrawable(R.drawable.joe);
        }
    };
```

This runs perfectly, but when I add the setImageDrawable it crashes. 
EDIT: The drawable that I would like to change is in the intent that I am going to

Comment: Please clarify how you want the image to work: when do you want to change the image? When the list item is clicked? Or do you want to just load the image once for each list item when the whole list loads? Is the image in each list item or are you trying to load it somewhere else?

Comment: The image is in the drawables folder, It is currently bob and I want to change it to joe when I click bob.

Comment: so you want to display the image in the list item and when that list item is clicked, it changes the image?

Comment: or are you clicking the list item and changing an image in the `Activity` you are launching with the `Intent`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the image drawable in the `Activity` that you are launching with your `Intent`, not in the `ListView`. You could pass the name in with `intent.putExtras("name", name);`. Then in the `Activity` use `setImageDrawable` based on the name that you get from the `Intent` extra.

**EDIT**: Retrieving data from the `Intent` in your `Activity`:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String name = intent.getStringExtra("name");
```

And then something like this to set the Player `ImageView`:

```
if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("joe")
    Player.setImageDrawable(R.drawable.joe);
```

Comment: so can you tell me what the code would be like to get the extras?

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting your content view. You should set as:

```
ImageView player;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.your_list_layout);   //   <-- setting content view
  player = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.bob);
.
.
.
```

Comment: sorry, i forgot to mention, the picture i wanna change is in the other intent that I am going to, and also, that doesn't work because the content is already mentioned in the array adapter